# Which technology is recommended to use as Audio Streaming Web Server

Tags: performance, io, audio-streaming, fileserver

I have a client side software which directly streams audio from a fileserver with public multimedia files exposed.

I'm using AWS S3 like web services, and I'm trying to maintain file hosting costs the lowest (Currently 0$). *So any paid solution for data storage has been already reviewed.*

The file collection size is really increasing. It might be close to 10TB of files during the next 12 months.
For now I manage around 250Gb of diverse quality mp3 files and images.

---

I would like to implement a **server for streaming multimedia files**, and I would like some advice in which server architecture/technology to use for this purpose (Hadoop, Nginx, ..)

First requisites might be:

- good I/O management
- handling many persistent and durable connections
  for streaming.

> The file security is not an issue in this question

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing special about audio files vs. any others for this use case.  Any web server will do.

You're already using S3, just use that.  S3 can serve your files directly, but with any decent load you're going to want to use CloudFront in front of your S3 bucket.  CloudFront is a CDN that will distribute your media files from geographically distributed points, keeping things nice and fast for your users.  It's also often cheaper to use CloudFront than S3 directly, when you have more traffic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The point of my question is that data volume is about to increase up to "non reasonable" costs, and I'm thinking about creating a test datacenter. Then which software could I use as a single node (for starting) of a cdn, as you nicely sketch...

Comment: @Karlos I'm not sure I understand your question.  You're going to build your own data center to try to compete with the pricing of S3... for music distribution via HTTP?  And, you're looking for software?  It's going to be far cheaper for you to use an existing CDN.  And, for general durable storage on a system with the flexibility of S3, you'll be hard pressed to find something cheaper.  Backblaze has an API-driven storage service now, but it's not really the same product as S3.

Comment: Thanks Brad, In fact we use some accounts on Backblaze for their free solution which is twice the S3. We are thinking about using the same approach with Mega, which offers 10x time storage quota than S3 having also other drawbacks. The Backblaze solution is covering for now the application needs, moving forward is a must now for us. Payment or _diy_ might be the difference. Is there any technology doing a good network I/O management and at the same time, optimizing the system I/O operations?

Comment: @Karlos You're going to have to be far more specific about what you mean by that last sentence.  At this point, I'm not understanding at all what you are trying to do.

Comment: I mean any web-server specially good for managing streaming. By system I/O operations, I wonder to store files raid-like locally in distributed servers. I would install the technology I ask for in those servers which are load balanced each other.

Comment: @Karlos Any web server will do... you actually **don't** want special features for audio streaming in this case.  As long as your HTTP server supports range requests (and almost all do), that's all you need.  (This would be different if you were doing live streaming.)  I use Nginx usually.  For distributed storage something like HDFS or GridFS would work nicely... but you're going to spend a lot more money and time on doing this yourself, especially because S3 can already handle the serving portion for you.